# Android launcher icon has rough edges

Tags: android, icons, launcher, android-launcher, android-icons

So my tablet recently updated to Android 7.1.1, and I noticed that my app's icon looked like hot garbage with the new adaptive icon scheme.  I updated things via Android Studio's Image Asset Studio, and it's better, but I'm noticing the edges of the squared circle look kind of ragged/jagged/rough.  Here's how it looks compared to Twitter and Firefox.  Any suggestions as to how I can get the edges of mine to look as smooth as those?

EDIT: For what it's worth I still see the same rough edges if I use an image or plain color as the background, and they even show up with the stock ic_launcher icon.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[You Change the Shape here in Image Assest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgxNK.png)

Comment: So it turns out that's actually where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the image asset tool in Android Studio is creating the problem - it leaves transparent edges around the generated icons.  And then when it's rendered on the device, Android rescales things as a result, which leads to the indistinct edges on the icons.  What worked for me was to go back in and fill in the transparent areas by hand so that the background extends all the way out to the edges of the .png files.